# Cleaned data not reaching model - django rest auth

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to pass data from my angularJS app, to django using django-rest-auth.

In my console, I can see the data reaches correctly (particularly 'gender' and 'yob').

However, it seems that after "cleaned_data" gets called- the data does not end up in my django user model

Note- I've got two user models set up (one is the stock django User table, the other is a User table I've created in models.py)

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter  # refer to allauth.account.adapter
from stashd.models import User, AccountProfile
import datetime, json


class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):

        system_account = super(StashdAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, user, form, commit)
        print form
## Print form shows all the data, but the cleaned_data get's rid of it
        data = form.cleaned_data
        first_name = data.get('first_name')
        username = data.get('username')
        last_name = data.get('last_name')
        email = data.get('email')
        # gender = data.get('gender')
        # yob = data.get('yob') 
        # dob = datetime.date(int(yob), 1, 1)
        info = {}
        # for k, v in [('first', username), ('first', first_name), ('last', last_name), ('email', email)]:
        #     if v:
        #         info[k] = v
        for k, v in [('email', email)]: #,('dob',dob),('gender',gender)
            if v:
                info[k] = v

        user = User(**info)
        user.save()

        AccountProfile(user=user, account=system_account).save()

        return system_account
```

Comment: Can you check for errors in form (`print form._errors`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` on the form to populate the cleaned_data

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it in your code and was my best go at a quick solution :) Where are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

In django documentation it is stated that,

> Once you’ve created a Form instance with a set of data and validated
>   it, you can access the clean data via its cleaned_data attribute

You can refer documentation of it from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).